# Why is call by reference so much slower than inline code?

Tags: c++, performance, methods

I am programming a physics simulation with few particles (typically 3, no more than 5).

In a condensed version my code structure like this:

```
#include<iostream>

class Particle{
  double x; // coordinate
  double m; // mass
};


void performStep(Particle &p, double &F_external){
   p.x += -0.2*p.x + F_external/p.m; // boiled down, in reality complex calculation, not important here
}
 
int main(){

 dt = 0.001; // time step, not important

 Particle p1;
 p1.x = 5; // some random number for initialization, in reality more complex but not important here
 p.m = 1;

 Particle p2;
 p2.x = -1; // some random numbersfor initialization, in reality more complex but not important here
 p.m = 2;

 Particle p3;
 p3.x = 0; // some random number for initialization, in reality more complex but not important here
 p.m = 3;

 double F_external = 0; // external forces

 for(unsigned long long int i=0; i < 10000000000; ++i){ // many steps, typically 10e9
    F_external = sin(i*dt);
    performStep(p1, F_external);
    performStep(p2, F_external);
    performStep(p3, F_external);
 }

 std::cout << "p1.x: " << p1.x << std::endl;
 std::cout << "p2.x: " << p2.x << std::endl;
 std::cout << "p3.x: " << p3.x << std::endl;

}
```

I have determined with `clock()` that the `performStep(p, F_external)` call is the bottleneck in my code).
When I tried to do inline calculation, i.e. replace `performStep(p1, F_external)` by `p1.x += -0.2*p1.x + F_external/p1.m;` the calculation suddenly was roughly a factor of 2 faster. Note that performStep() in reality is about ~60 basic arithmetic calculations over ~20 lines, so the code becomes really bloated if I just inline it for every particle.

Why is that the case? I am compiling with MinGW64/g++ and the -O2 flag. I thought the compiler would optimize such things?

**Edit:**

Here is the function that is called. Note that in reality, I calculate all three coordinates x,y,z with a couple of different external forces. Variables which are not passed via the function are a member of `SimulationRun`. The algorithm is a fourth-order [leapfrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) algorithm.

```
void SimulationRun::performLeapfrog_z(const unsigned long long int& i, const double& x, const double& y, double& z, const double& vx, const double& vy, double& vz, const double& qC2U0, 
    const double& U0, const double& m, const double& C4, const double& B2, const double& f_minus, const double& f_z, const double& f_plus, const bool& bool_calculate_xy,
    const double& Find, const double& Fheating) {

    // probing for C4 == 0 and B2 == 0 saves some computation time
    if (C4 == 0) {
        Fz_C4_Be = 0;
    }
    if (B2 == 0 || !bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_B2_Be = 0;
    }


    z1 = z + c1 * vz * dt;


    if (C4 != 0 && !bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_C4_Be = (-4) * q * C4 * U0 * z1 * z1 * z1;
    }
    else if (C4 != 0 && bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_C4_Be = q * C4 * U0 * (-4 * z1 * z1 * z1 + 6 * z1 * (x * x + y * y));
    }
    if (B2 != 0 && bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_B2_Be = q * B2 * (-vx * z1 * y + vy * z1 * x);
    }
    acc_z1 = (qC2U0 * (-2) * z1 + Find + Fz_C4_Be + Fz_B2_Be + Fheating) / m;
    vz1 = vz + d1 * acc_z1 * dt;
    z2 = z1 + c2 * vz1 * dt;


    if (C4 != 0 && !bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_C4_Be = (-4) * q * C4 * U0 * z2 * z2 * z2;
    }
    else if (C4 != 0 && bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_C4_Be = q * C4 * U0 * (-4 * z2 * z2 * z2 + 6 * z2 * (x * x + y * y));
    }
    if (B2 != 0 && bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_B2_Be = q * B2 * (-vx * z2 * y + vy * z2 * x);
    }
    acc_z2 = (qC2U0 * (-2) * z2 + +Find + Fz_C4_Be + Fz_B2_Be + Fheating) / m;
    vz2 = vz1 + d2 * acc_z2 * dt;
    z3 = z2 + c3 * vz2 * dt;

    if (C4 != 0 && !bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_C4_Be = (-4) * q * C4 * U0 * z3 * z3 * z3;
    }
    else if (C4 != 0 && bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_C4_Be = q * C4 * U0 * (-4 * z3 * z3 * z3 + 6 * z3 * (x * x + y * y));
    }
    if (B2 != 0 && bool_calculate_xy) {
        Fz_B2_Be = q * B2 * (-vx * z3 * y + vy * z3 * x);
    }
    acc_z3 = (qC2U0 * (-2) * z3 + Find + Fz_C4_Be + Fz_B2_Be + Fheating) / m;
    vz3 = vz2 + d3 * acc_z3 * dt;

    z = z3 + c4 * vz3 * dt;
    vz = vz3;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Isn't your loop asking for 10^10 iterations, which overflows the `unsigned int`?

Comment: You may want to post the rest of `performStep()`. Passing a reference is more involved than passing a simple pointer in C. I don't off the top of my head have a list of how that would impact the efficiency of `performStep()`, but at least seeing how the references are used may point some of the smart folks here in the right direction.

Comment: In this simple case, I would have expected the `sin` calculation to be predominent. You might try to compile with O3, but I am anyway surprised by your result.

Comment: Or go ahead a compile with `-Ofast` and give it all the compiler has to give.

Comment: @j6t Indeed, I actually use a unsigned long long int. I edited it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I will do so

Comment: @Damien It's competitive, in the faster version it is roughly 1:1. But I guess optimizing the function calls is easier

Comment: If `F_external` does not get modified inside the (real) function, you should pass it as `const double &F_external` so that the compiler has one less thing to worry about. Or just pass it by value.

Comment: you say `boiled down, in reality complex calculation, not important here` but actually it is critical as the complexity of the function is one of the main criteria the compiler uses to decide whether to inline or not, please provide a [mre]. E.g. your code does inline with gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/E5oeW4

Comment: What *exact* compilation are you doing? Consider using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in December 2020) as `g++ -flto -Wall -Ofast` used both at compilation and linking time. I recommend using it on a recent [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/)

Comment: I am using Rcpp and the compilation output is `/mingw64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Users/christian/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'     -std=c++11   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c myRcppFile.cpp -o myRcppFile.o`

Comment: could you try to pass only a single pointer to a struct to the function? It could be that you are just spending too much time just copying parameters into the stack, as you are using too many function parameters and the compiler might be using the stack instead of using  registers. Try using a struct which takes all of the parameters, and passing a pointer to it. Also, try to take out of any loop the copy of the parameters into it.

Comment: Also, if you are using simple types, don't use const reference, just use them by value. It will simplify the code and the compiler does not have to worry about derreferencing them (despite differences, you can think of them in the same way as pointers, which have to be derreferenced, despite not having to use the arrow -> ). The derreferencing has a cost, which in this case is not needed

Comment: Also the compiler does not have to worry about aliasing if you pass by (const) value.

Answer (score 0):

Optimization is hard, even for compilers. Here are some optimization tips:

1. Since your `performStep` is hotspot, put it into a header file(in case that you split declaration and definition into header/source), then add `inline` keyword, like:

```
// at file xxx.h
inline void performStep(Particle &p, double F_external){
   p.x += -0.2*p.x + F_external/p.m; // boiled down, in reality complex calculation, not important here
}
```

2. Upgrade your compiler, maybe to the latest.
3. use https://godbolt.org/ to check the assembly code. In this case, unnecessary dereference is the headache of performance.

Comment: The `inline` keyword confusingly has little/nothing to do with compiler inlining optimisations, it mostly prevents linker errors when the same function is defined in multiple translation units

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, helpful as it might be.